# Apply style to p tags directly after h1 tag until it hits another h tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I apply a CSS style to all P tags directly after a H1 tag? But only until it hits another H1, H2 etc?

I have tried the following:

**This only does the first P...**

```
h1 + p {
  color:red
}
```

**This does ALL P's after the H1 for the rest of the page...**

```
h1 ~ p {
  color:red
}
```

**This works but want something recurring...**

```
h1 + p + p {
  color:red
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/wdmo5rhx/

Comment: the method's you described are prettymuch your only chance with just pure css, find all type of selectors here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. but i think with the addition of some javascript you can get this to work

Comment: That is not possible in any direct way. You could only format all `p` that follow the _2nd_  `h1` (assuming you can identify _that one_ somehow) differently again, to reverse the effect of what you applied to the first ones.

Comment: consider taking a look here: https://api.jquery.com/nextall/

Answer (score 1):

sorted using jquery:

```
$("h1").nextUntil(":not(p)").addClass("special_p");
```

css:

```
.special_p{color:red}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wdmo5rhx/1/